# Linux 'grep' only highlights but doesn't filter

Tags: linux, grep

question is in the title.

I'm trying to perform 
   "du -sh * | grep '^[0-9]'" 
on my root dir to filter out any ... cannot access ..., but my console will just color matches and print out everything.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a command, it will always open 3 files: `stdin` (keyboard input), `stdout` (command output) and `stderr` (command output for error messages), these are numbered from 0 to 2.

Those error messages from `du` are written to `stderr`, while the normal output is written to `stdout`. This allows you to [redirect](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) the error messages to [/dev/null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device). This makes the error messages disappear, you don't need grep for that.

```
du -sh * 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: thanks alot, i was banging my head against the wall the last half an hour because of this :D